# How to scroll mat-select option top after closing the mat-select?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-material, material-ui

How to scroll mat-select option top after closing the mat-select?

I have many option in my mat-select. I select one option from bottom. Now, after open mat-select again, I want the list from top.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to *openChange* event and reset scroll position of the scrollable element every time MatSelect opens:

```
@ViewChild('selectElement') selectElement: MatSelect;

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectElement.openedChange.subscribe((isOpen: boolean) => {
    if (isOpen) {
      const panel = this.selectElement.panel.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
      panel.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-asxwdo?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I have tried it but when i open the dropdown it first open the botton value then goes to the top. I want to show from top position only. @Andrey Etumyan